# Core Plot : Grid lines appear once per two plots

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

Am using Core Plot to plot some memory statistics for an iPhone App. Here is a sample plot

[image]

Why is the grid line appearing only for every alternating plot? I want it to appear for every plot. How do I do it? Here's the code where I configure the grid line.

```
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5f;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor]; //[[CPTColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6f];
    axisSet.xAxis.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `majorGridLineStyle` is for the grid lines at the major tick locations, i.e., the ones with the labels in your sample image. Set the `minorGridLineStyle` to draw lines at the minor tick locations between the major ticks. The two line styles can be different, for example to emphasize the major grid lines.

Comment: Thanks, @EricSkroch, let me check and get back

Comment: Hi @EricSkroch, could you tell please if major gridlines can be configured to be displayed not for each major tick, but for each x-th (e.g. for each 4th, 6th etc).

Comment: @SergeyN. No. Ask a new question so we don't pollute the comments on this one and I'll expand on that answer.